# jQuery load before send

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am loading html content via jquery load. Is there a method similiar to jquery $.ajax beforesend for jQuery load. To display a gif spinner while the content is loading

```
jQuery('.content').load(this.toString());
```

Comment: just wondering, what is `this`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not very complicated, show the spinner before the load, and hide it in the callback when the load has completed

```
$('#gifSpinner').show();
$('.content').load(this.toString(), function() {
    $('#gifSpinner').hide();
});
```

Comment: your answer is right. however there is    $("#div_loading").ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
        $("#div_loading").ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });